# Write a class Car with a constructor that accepts a yearModel, a make, and a speed (in MPH) as its argument

Tags: java

So we are expected to write a class Car that accepts model, make and speed as an argument. We are given the main method to run and are just expected to write the class that includes and Accelerate (add 5 mph to speed) and brake ( decrease 5 mph but never below 0).

The main method gives us these lines of code to set the argument:

```
Car a = new Car(2008, "Toyota", 0);
Car b = new Car(2017, "Ford", 20);
Car c = new Car(2012, "Volvo", 6);
Car [] test_field = {a, b, c};
```

the calls in the main are shown as

```
for(int i = 0; i < test_field.length; i++){
    test_field[i].accelerate();
   }
}
else{
     for(int i = 0; i<test_field.length; i++){
        test_field[i].brake();
}
```

when writing the method, i keep getting a method in class Car cannot be applied to given types for both my accelerate and brake methods when i try to run and I cant seem to figure out my issue.

my code:

```
public class Car {

private int yearModel;
private String make;
private int speed;

   public Car() {

   }
   public Car(int ym, String m, int sp) {

   yearModel = ym;
   make = m;
   speed = sp;
 } 
   public void setModel(int ym) {
   yearModel = ym;
   }
   public void setMake(String m) {
   make = m;
   }
   public void setSpeed(int sp) {
   speed = sp;

   }


  public int accelerate(Car c) {

  speed = speed + 5;

  return speed;

  }
  public int brake(Car c) {
 speed = speed - 5;

  if (speed < 0) {
  speed = 0;
  return speed;
  }

  else return speed;

  }
}
```

any input or insight for a novice coder appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why does your accelerate and brake methods require a Car object in the method signature?

`public int accelerate(Car c)`

You also don't pass a Car object when you call the method.

`test_field[i].accelerate();`

Since you don't do anything with `c` in the method, you can remove that argument.

Should look like this:

```
public int accelerate() {
    speed = speed + 5;
    return speed;
}

public int brake() {
    speed = speed - 5;
    if (speed < 0) {
        speed = 0;
        return speed;
    }
    else {
        return speed;
    }
}
```